# C++ .NET declare variables

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have just started working in VC++. I am using .NET 4 and I don't know where I can declare global vars.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/xTU36gfU) is the simple code automatically created. Where can I declare variables?

Is putting all vars in another .h a good idea?

Comment: Please post the code into the question. What happens if the PasteBin link expires? Your question becomes worthless to future users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
int g_nX; // global variable


void Main()
{
    int nY; // local variable nY

    // global vars can be seen everywhere in program
    // so we can change their values here
    g_nX = 5;
} // nY is destroyed here
```

Comment: i do not have main() in Forms application

Comment: obviously i added just sample of global variable and local variable iamnp, Thank's for your remark

Comment: That's not a global variable, it's an instance variable of the Program class.  Prefix with `static`.  Also the syntax for C++/CLI, the language he's asking about.